# How to remove options from select if already exist or selected?

Tags: php, select, exists

I want to remove or hide already selected/exist layout name/id from select `<option>`.

**If layout option :**

Home

Page 1

Page 2

Page 3

**If layout option `Home` already selected ( hide/remove `home` ) :**

Page 1

Page 2

Page 3

```
<select name="layout"> <?php foreach ($layouts as $layout) { ?> 

   <?php if ($layout['layout_id'] == $my['layout_id']) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo  $layout['layout_id'];  ?>" selected="selected">
                  <?php  echo $layout['name'];  ?>
            </option> 

       <?php } else { ?> 

           <option value="<?php echo $layout['layout_id']; ?>">
               <?php echo $layout['name']; ?>
           </option>
       <?php } ?> 

  <?php } ?> 

</select>
```

Comment: There is no need to spray your code with `<?php` and `?>` It just makes it almost unreadable. If you have 2 consecutive lines of PHP then one `<?php` at the start  and one `?>` at the end is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove/comment the code below:

```
<?php if ($layout['layout_id'] == $my['layout_id']) { ?>
       <!-- <option value="<?php echo  $layout['layout_id'];  ?>" selected="selected">
                  <?php  echo $layout['name'];  ?>
            </option> -->

       <?php } else { ?>
```

You are already checking the current page in loop.

No need for extra efforts, use that logic only as hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `array_diff`? Create two arrays, `$layouts` and `$existing` and then do the following:

```
<?php
//Set $layouts and $existing to proper array values
$results = array_diff($layouts, $existing); //Where the results will be Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 (not Home)

//Do stuff here (i.e. foreach loop through $results array)
?>
```

Then you don't have to check if it already exists, and you don't have to iterate through each item if it already exists. You can just iterate through each element that you know is not a duplicate. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for more information about `array_diff`

Comment: Can you `print_r($array)` each array and see what values exist in both arrays?